# Nginx rewrite without redirect

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want url `domain.com/foo-111` to load contents from directory `/bar/111` but not change url.

I created a rewrite rule but instead of loading contents of proper directory, it 301 redirects to domain.com/bar/111

My server config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;

  location / {
      root /var/www/domain.com;
      index index.html index.htm;
      rewrite ^/foo-(.*)$ /bar/$1 break;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nginx` is trying to add a trailing `/` to turn the URI into the correct format for a directory spec. Add the `/` in your `rewrite` so that `nginx` doesn't have to. Try this:

```
 rewrite ^/foo-(.*?)/?$ /bar/$1/ break;
```